# Why did the lower built in filter not work in Django template 2.2?

Tags: django, django-templates

Using `Django v2.2` built-in filters for templates.

my template looks like this:

```
    {% load i18n %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.organization.name site_domain=current_site.name %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!

    You're receiving this e-mail because your email is subscribed to receiving notification when a Quotation is Pending PO Release.

    {{ quote_type }}
    {{ quote_type|lower }}

     - Quotation: {{ display_quotation_number }}
     - PO Date: {{ po_date_display }} (New)

    {% endblocktrans %}

    {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.organization.name site_domain=current_site.name %}Thank you for using {{ site_name }}!
    {{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

I can say with certainty that `{{ quote_type }}` definitely prints something out. `{{ quote_type|lower }}` prints nothing.

What did I do wrong?

I was certain that the filter is builtin; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#lower

#### UPdate

This is my current workard and it works

```
    extra_context = self.lower_quote_type(extra_context)
    quotation.email_people(
        recipient_list=recipient_list,
        extra_context=extra_context,
    )

def lower_quote_type(self, extra_context):
        # @makeAnIssue temp workard for #1334 but try to permanently fix it elegantly
        if "quote_type" in extra_context:
            extra_context["quote_type"] = extra_context["quote_type"].lower()
        return extra_context
```

Then this works

```
    {% load i18n %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.organization.name site_domain=current_site.name %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!

    You're receiving this e-mail because your email is subscribed to receiving notification when a Quotation is Pending PO Release.

    {{ quote_type }} # this correctly shows up as lower case


     - Quotation: {{ display_quotation_number }}
     - PO Date: {{ po_date_display }} (New)

    {% endblocktrans %}

    {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.organization.name site_domain=current_site.name %}Thank you for using {{ site_name }}!
    {{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the variable `quote_type` in the template is of type `str` ? If it is a different class then that could cause the filter to return nothing because an error gets raised inside the filter.

Comment: Well, my current work ard is to lowercase it first before passing it in, so I'm pretty confident, it's `str`